# Drawing lines at angle vb.net

Tags: vb.net, draw, angle

I can find plenty of examples of how to draw a line in vb.net online.

I however I cannot find any examples of how to draw lines at a specific angle.

Could someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a bit of math using `sin`/`cos`.

`x1`, `y1` = starting position of line
`angleInRadians` = angle on the line converted to Radians

```
x2 = lineLength * Math.Cos(angleInRadians) + x1
y2 = lineLength * Math.Sin(angleInRadians) + y1
```

Then you can draw a line from (`x1`, `y1`) to (`x2`, `y2`).

Comment: I cant see how this works (cant get it to work cause the example is incomplete)

Comment: The line fonctione draw from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2). You need two vertex to draw the line. If you one have one vertex and an angle. This formula will give you the second vertex (x2, y2).