# Drawing a line when given is center point, angle and length

Tags: vb.net

I have seen this solution: [Drawing lines at angle vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215247/drawing-lines-at-angle-vb-net)
for my question, but I need clarification on the answer. (I could not add comment in that post, because I don't have enough reputation to do so.)

My specific requirement is: basically draw two lines on either side of the given center point at given angle and given length.

```
    Dim stPt As New clsNode
    stPt.X = 2000 * Math.Cos(RadAngle) + v_center.X
    stPt.Y = 2000 * Math.Sin(RadAngle) + v_center.Y

    'Get EndPoint
    Dim edpt As New clsNode
    How can I get endpoint?
```

I am using vb.net.

Comment: So, What's the actual problem ? got any error? or nothing happening in Front-End ?

Comment: For End point I tried this: edpt.X = -2000 * Math.Cos(RadAngle) + v_center.X       But this gave me wrong point. So I am not sure what to do for the opposite side of the center from stpt.

Comment: My crystal balls says that you forgot that the angle needs to be in radians, not degrees.  The opposite side is at RadAngle + Math.Pi.  If that's not accurate then you must show us an example with variable values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Hans Passant: You were correct. So this is final code:

```
    Dim RadAngle As Double = v_dAngle * (Math.PI / 180)

    'Get StartPoint
    Dim stPt As New clsNode
    stPt.X = 2000 * Math.Cos(RadAngle) + v_center.X
    stPt.Y = 2000 * Math.Sin(RadAngle) + v_center.Y

    'Get EndPoint
    Dim edpt As New clsNode
    edpt.X = -2000 * Math.Cos(RadAngle) + v_center.X
    edpt.Y = -2000 * Math.Sin(RadAngle) + v_center.Y

    Return New clsNode() {stPt, edpt}.ToList
```